# Run a Jenkins job every one minute using H/1 * * * *

Tags: jenkins, build, cron, job-scheduling, periodic-processing

How can I run a job created in Jenkins every one minute ? Am I missing anything?

PS: I'm trying not to use: ***/1 * * * ***

[image]
[image]

Comment: Was it necessary to post pictures of text?

Comment: @IanW AI ML ... can help SO website one day!

Comment: And when the day comes that "AI ML ... can help SO website", it won't be users helping users, so we won't worry about people deciphering pictures of text. In the meantime, you can help your fellow helpers today; [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/). Or if you have time to throw together, the AI ML thing, fell free to contribute...

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Try `* * * * *` to run every minute.

Unfortunately `H/1 * * * *` does not work due to open defect.

Defect: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22129

Comment: The idea is to use H (so that Jenkins can to balance) if there are hundreds of jobs who have the same build period. */1 * * * * will do the same.

Comment: The question is more towards using H instead of * i.e. why H/1 * * * * is picking/scheduling the job for 1 hour difference (instead of 1 minute difference) while H/2 * * * * schedules the job for 2 minutes (as expected).

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. There seems to be an open defect - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22129

Comment: Stiil have to use * * * * *

Comment: would this work? H(0-59)/1 * * * *

Answer (score 16):

Your intuition is right, `H/1` is **supposed** to behave like "run every minute".

However, there is a well-known bug in Jenkins. See [JENKINS-22129](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22129).

Currently, `H/1` behaves like "run every hour".

Answer (score 0):

Use this format it will Run a Jenkins job every one minute "* * * * *"

Comment: Hey pravi, this was mentioned in another answer many years ago.  Try to avoid adding repeat answers.

Comment: No, this is supposed to work but it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

To run the build process every minute,
check the Build periodically option and add `* * * * *`